# How to write conditional statements in bitbucket pipelines.yml file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to bitbucket pipelines and trying to deploy my code via bitbucket pipelines by using javaScript.
My question is can we declare variables like (ex: var flag = false) and then write if/else statements based the flag value.

Below is my pipelines.yml file

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:12.18.2

pipelines:
branches: # deploying as per branches
 feature/pocDepTerex: # poc master branch
    - step: 
       caches:
        - node
       script: 
         - node -v
```

Here, I want to declare a flag and run the script node -v only when the flag is true.

Please let me know if there is any way to do it in pipelines

Answer (score 17):

You sure can! Whilst you're probably used to writing a series of one-line commands in **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**, you can use [standard YAML syntax](https://yaml-multiline.info) to insert multiline content. For example:

```
image: node:12.18.2

pipelines:
branches: # deploying as per branches
 feature/pocDepTerex: # poc master branch
    - step: 
       caches:
        - node
       script: 
         - export MY_FLAG=true
         - |
           if [ "$MYFLAG" = true ]; then
             node -v
           fi
```

Full disclosure: I work for Atlassian, though not on the Bitbucket Pipelines team :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got the below error on trying this way

bash: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/bashScript7015344215178746479.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: That might be my bad - YAML multiline syntax suggests `>` to use "folded" style, where newlines are interpreted as spaces; or `|` to use "literal" style, where newlines are preserved. In an if/then statement, a newline or `;` is expected after `then`. I updated my answer, give it another try

Comment: now its giving following error:
+ export MY_FLAG=true - | if [ "$MYFLAG" = true ]; then node -v fi
bash: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/bashScript6392172108976259935.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: hey it seems a '-' was missing before  fi. it worked when i added - fi :)   thanks for your help

Comment: still wondering why bitbucket is not supporting conditional steps in their pipelines (only based on changesets...)

Comment: they don't even allow setting multiple directories for one cache. and their official documentation on "how to monorepo" suggests not to use a monorepo. LOL

Answer (score 13):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62977257/7126793) posted by daveruninseverything works perfectly fine when the steps involved are shell-type commands but not helpful when Bitbucket pipes are being used. (For more information on Bitbucket pipes click [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-are-pipes/))

Following line can be added just before an execution of Bitbucket pipe as shown below in order to implement a conditional:

```
- if [ "$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE" != test ]; then exit 0 ; fi
- pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.4
```

The above added lines ensure that the `pipe` will be executed only if the workspace name is `test`.